# How to insert text displayed by span inside input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

```js
document.querySelector('.input').value = document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML
    document.querySelector('.text').textContent = 'Here is the text';
```

```html
<span class='text'></span>
<input class='input' />
```

How can I insert "Here is the text" inside the input form.

Comment: Are you trying to update the span as characters are typed into the input box?

Comment: what is "input form"? do you mean the "input field"?

Answer (score 0):

You just had the 2 lines reversed.
Also, You'll probably want to wrap it in a window.load listener to make sure it fires after the page has rendered

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.text').textContent = 'Here is the text';
  document.querySelector('.input').value = document.querySelector('.text').innerText
})
```

```html
<span class='text'></span>
<input class='input' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value after you set the `span`'s `textContent`, otherwise the `innerHTML` property willl be `""` since at that time the `span` didn't have any content:

```js
document.querySelector('.text').textContent = 'Here is the text';
document.querySelector('.input').value = document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML
```

```html
<span class='text'></span>
<input class='input' />
```